# Hyper-V Server Backup

Tags: backup, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I have a VM installed in Hyper-V on my server. I run Windows Server Backups everyday. I use the full bare metal option for server backup. I am guessing that if my VM ever crashed I could restore it from the backup. Would this be as easy as I other restore option would be? I ask because I have never had to restore my VM before.

Comment: Have you tried seems easy enough to duplicate the VM and "restore" and learn from trial and error

Comment: @Ramhound Not yet, I guess that would be a good idea. Thanks for the input

Comment: @Ramhound I am in the process of doing that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restored my VM from the server backup. Then I crated a new VM in Hyper-V linking to the restored .VHD. Started the VM and everything worked fine.